# How do you indicate all dates in a date filter?

Tags: forms, filter, dates

We have some filters for a table of data like below:

[image]

Meaning it can be filtered by status and / or start / end dates. Status has an "All" option meaning to show all status. However, when it comes to date, how do we indicate "All Dates" as clicking on the date fields will just trigger a calendar.

Answer (score 1):

I find the way Google Search does it the most intuitive way:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Keep the date field empty with just the icon in the right. It is the simple way to understand that the date is by default set to show all dates.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but I think it's as simple as adding a checkbox for "All dates" and disabling (greying out) the calendar selectors when the checkbox is ticked. You don't have to bundle this 'all dates' range into your calendars, because it adds unnecessary complexity. Simple is good, right?

Answer (score 0):

Here I upload the image which can be good solution to your problem. I hope it will help you. And if you are not getting then let me know.[image]